# Can I disable a particular local notification banner when app is in foreground?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification

My application is currently set up to display local and push notifications even when in the foreground. There is one specific local notification I would like to disable when in the foreground, but keep enabled when the app is not active or in the background. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: When app in foreground iOS will not show notification banner/alert by default on its own, you must have written code or used a third party frameworks to show some banner on App, just put a break point in that code to not to show the specific notification

Answer (score -1):

When app in foreground iOS will not show notification banner/alert by default on its own, you must have written code or used a third party frameworks to show some banner on App, just put a break point in that code to not to show the specific notification
https://github.com/nhdang103/HDNotificationView

Comment: It does from iOS 10